# How can I open a file from a location that everyone has but under a different name?

Tags: python

I'm trying to open a .txt file under the appdata folder but I cannot understand how to make python open from a specified directory with different names

```
import os
f=open("os.getenv('APPDATA')/Local/filedir/filename.txt",'r+')
```

that's what i came up with after few minutes of googling but i don't really know how should i implement os.getenv('APPDATA') to work. if i print it,it says the right path but if i put it together with the rest of the path it says it cannot find it.

Comment: You need to put it into a variable first then join it to the rest of the path. Putting `"os.getenv('APPDATA')"` in a string doesn't evaluate it.

Comment: You mean `os.path.expanduser('~') + "\\AppData\\Local\\filedir\\filename.txt"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your code, you're telling python to open a file with the path `os.getenv(...` while you should be using the value *returned* by `os.getenv`.

According to [this](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html), Windows has its own environment variable for the `Local` directory, namely `LOCALAPPDATA`. This should work (I'm not on Windows, so I'm unable to put it to the test):

```
import os
subpath ="filedir/filename.txt"
print os.path.join(os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA"), subpath)
```

Comment: For me in Windows `os.getenv("APPDATA")` gives `Roaming` folder under AppData

Comment: @LearningNeverStops updated the answer to include how to get `Roaming`'s parent directory.